# FFMpeg : Falied to combine two MPEG TS files into a Single MP4 File

Tags: android, video, command-line, ffmpeg

I'm trying to combine **2 .ts files** in to a **single .mp4** file here using **FFMpeg**. I need to make the **concat dumuxer** method working in order to use it in my Android App. In my android app the **concat protocol** is not recognized. So I'm trying the **concat demuxer method**.

The **concat protocol** works fine in my **windows pc** :

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:s1.ts|s2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

But, the **concat demuxer** is not working in my windows pc :

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i s1.ts -i s2.ts -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output2.mp4

Error : 
[concat @ 0000000000516e00] Line 1: unknown keyword 'G@'
s1.ts: Invalid data found when processing input
```

[image]

There are the files used for the testing:
http://fourbigbrothers.com/s1.ts  And http://fourbigbrothers.com/s2.ts

Pls help. I've been chewing my brains lately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concat demuxer requires a text file as input, which contains the names of the videos in the following format:

```
file 's1.ts'
file 's2.ts'
```

And the command will be

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output2.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks mulvya. I tried using this method still getting same error.

Comment: Works here. Run your command with `-report` and upload the report.

Comment: Tried using -report.   Now it's **Line 1: unknown keyword 'G@'
s1.ts: Invalid data found when processing input**

Comment: Upload the report and the concat text file.

Comment: It works. it was my fault that I accidentally put an extra space in between. Thanks a lot for your time and support. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you know how to build the latest ffmpeg to Android application?

Comment: Thanks Mulvya. Thanks a lot for your time :)